# i get a error whan i put my usb in

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive

Here is a screen shot of my error
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USsEh.png)

Comment: Please run `cat /etc/fstab` and paste the result here by updating your question.

Comment: It looks like it an installer of Elementary. What is the point of mounting it?

Comment: If you've copied the Loki.iso file to sdb1 and are trying to mount the .iso image... you can't do it like that. Exactly what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Read about TestDisk here --> [Tesdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

It will rebuild the partition table so you can get to the data. I think it will work on your usb drive.

It's a `command lines tool` but you should be able to find a how-to for it.

TestDisk is in the repositories:

`sudo apt-get install testdisk`

Hope it`d work for you!

Comment: how do i use testdisk :(

Comment: Take a look to this: [TestDsik](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/testdisk) You should translate page with the webrowser you are using.

Run Testdisk opening a terminal and type `testdisk` in it and hit enter.